# jqGrid with loadonce set to true,can not paing after reset rowobject

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

loadonce set to true, and I want to modify source data,than reload the grid on local,but after I use 
   $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam'{data:returnedData});
I don't know how to reload it,and the paging can not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use .trigger("reloadGrid")?

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam'{data:returnedData}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```